# it will not show the logo the image next js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image, nextjs-rewrites

unable to see the image

{/* Mobil Navigation */}

```
    <div className='sm:hidden flex relative'>
         {isUserLoggedIn ? (
        <div className='flex'> 
          <Image src='/assets/images/logo.svg' width={37} height={37} className='rounded-full'  alt='profile' onClick={() => setToggleDropdown((prev)=> !prev )}
          />
          {
            toggleDropdown && (<div className='dropdown'> 
              <Link href='/profile' className='dropdown_link' onClick={()=> {}}>
                  My Profile
                </Link>
             </div>
            )}
           </div>
           
        ):(
          <>
          {
            providers && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
              <button type='button'
              key={provider.name}
              onClick={()=> signIn(provider.id)}
              className='black_btn'>
                  signIn
              </button>
            ))}
          
          </>
      )}

      

            

    </div>
```

did I make a mistake? please review my code and assist,
(FYI the path of the src is correct I double checked it)